# rails 4 bootstrap 3 datepicker will not style bootstrap css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap datepicker one of my forms. I've already tried these paths https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails// github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails and the bootstrap css is not showing.

Currently I'm using this version https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails and have this /= require bootstrap-datetimepicker in my application.js and this `@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';` in my boostrap_and_overidescss.scss. The following is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insurance_start_date').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Any light onto this soul would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did get your problem solved? I'm the author of [this datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). Please let me know if I can help you

Comment: No. I temporary stepped away and just used the jQuery datepicker but if i do return I'll make sure to update this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a date picker, I think this has been upgraded to support BS3: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

If you want date and time, I think this is the one: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have not tried the latter because of some other frameworks that don't work yet (mostly simpleform), but these were what I came up with when I evaluated my upgrade path 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But somehow the datepicker css is not correctly being applied.

Comment: FYI: I went ahead and just took the datepicker from the jQuery widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the exact same gem you are, right now.

Not sure how much help I will be, though, but here's pointing out 2 things that may help.

1)  It could be a typo, but your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` appears to have the improper file extension.  yours seems to be missing a period between overides and css.

2)  What I did with this, to get the bootstrap working, was to just import it into my application css layout directly using `*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker`.  With that, I do have the bootstrap 'd calendar...although, I'm still having issues with getting the calendar to close after you've selected the date.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it turned out that jquery-UI was over-riding the bootstrap. Recompile in jquery-ui to not include datepicker.